# NodeJS - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The “path” argument must be of type string. Received undefined (mkdirp module nodejs)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a Node/Angular project that won't run because of this error. I am getting the following error:

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined`

More context for that error:

```
PS C:\Users\Vinay\retail-billpay-node> node server
internal/validators.js:124
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
    at resolve (path.js:139:9)
    at pathArg (C:\Users\Vinay\retail-billpay-node\node_modules\mkdirp\lib\path-arg.js:15:10)
    at mkdirp (C:\Users\Vinay\retail-billpay-node\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:10:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vinay\retail-billpay-node\app\helpers\winston.js:26:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vinay\retail-billpay-node\app\services\LogService.js:9:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

And here is my package.json if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "retail-billpay-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "start your node express app from this boilerplate code",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "siddhant-np",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "2.6.1",
    "bluebird": "3.5.3",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "crypto": "1.0.1",
    "csvtojson": "2.0.8",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "extract-zip": "1.6.7",
    "imap-simple": "4.3.0",
    "ioredis": "4.6.2",
    "kafka-node": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "md5": "2.2.1",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.21",
    "mongoose": "5.2.9",
    "nodemailer": "5.1.1",
    "otp.js": "1.1.0",
    "request": "2.87.0",
    "util": "0.11.1",
    "winston": "3.0.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "3.2.1",
    "xlsx": "0.14.1",
    "xml-parse": "0.3.1",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19",
    "xmlbuilder": "10.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add validator code to see the code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I got the solution thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I figured out the issue. I thought the error was telling me that path was undefined. When it fact it was saying the variables passed into path.join() were undefined. And that was because I forgot to add my .env file to the root so it could grab those variables.

Since it was an enterprise project so they don't keep .env file in the source code, I asked them and put it root.